# How to properly set condition on div checkmark?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to append a span tag with "Preferred" text into a div when a checkbox (a different span tag) is clicked and checkmark is present. When it is unchecked, the span tag with "Preferred" text should disappear.

However, I am having a hard time setting the condition correctly because it keeps going to the second condition where checkmark is not clicked or present.

```js
    $("#pref-a").unbind().click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            // $(this).attr('value', 'true');
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
            $("#pref-value1").append("<span style='position:relative; top:-13px; margin: 35px' class='label label-default'>Preferred</span>");
        } else {
            // $(this).attr('value', 'false');
            $(this).attr('checked', false);
            $("#pref-value1").children("span").remove();
        }
    });
```

```css
    /* The container */
    
    .container {
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 35px;
        /*margin-bottom: 16px;*/
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 15px;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
    /* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
    
    .container input {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
    }
    /* Create a custom checkbox */
    
    .checkmark {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
        background-color: #eee;
    }
    /* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
    
    .container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
    /* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
    
    .container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
        background-color: #2196F3;
    }
    /* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
    
    .checkmark:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
    }
    /* Show the checkmark when checked */
    
    .container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
        display: block;
    }
    /* Style the checkmark/indicator */
    
    .container .checkmark:after {
        left: 9px;
        top: 5px;
        width: 5px;
        height: 10px;
        border: solid white;
        border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    
    #Pref {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pref-value1" class="form-group Pref">
    <label class="container">
        <input id="checkbox1" name="preferred1" type="checkbox" value="false">
        <span id="pref-a" class="checkmark" style="margin: -2px 1px;" />
    </label>
</div>
```

I have tried many different conditions like:

```
($(this).prop(':checked')) or ($(this).is(':checked')) == false
```

However, it causes the same problem, or it adds multiple span tags with "Preferred" texts.

Can someone guide me on this please? Also, how would I get this function to work even though there's already a checkmark present initially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it looks like you almost have it. In your JS, you have the click event being listened to on the span tag, instead of the input tag.

Try this JS..where I first grab the ID of the checkbox(input), not the span tag.

```
$("#checkbox1").click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                // $(this).attr('value', 'true');
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
            $("#pref-value1").append("<span style='position:relative; top:-13px; margin: 35px' class='label label-default'>Preferred</span>");
        } else {
            // $(this).attr('value', 'false');
            $(this).attr('checked', false);
            $("#pref-value1").children("span").remove();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was the one that was posted the fastest, and at the same time, it worked for me. Like you said, I ended up grabbing the wrong target tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your JS code works fine, just you need to target the `<input id="checkbox1" ... >` by `$("#checkbox1").unbind().click(...)` instead of targeting `<span>`

```js
  $("#checkbox1").unbind().click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            // $(this).attr('value', 'true');
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
            $("#pref-value1").append("<span style='position:relative; top:-13px; margin: 35px' class='label label-default'>Preferred</span>");
        } else {
            // $(this).attr('value', 'false');
            $(this).attr('checked', false);
            $("#pref-value1").children("span").remove();
        }
    });
```

```css
    /* The container */
    
    .container {
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 35px;
        /*margin-bottom: 16px;*/
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 15px;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
    /* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
    
    .container input {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
    }
    /* Create a custom checkbox */
    
    .checkmark {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
        background-color: #eee;
    }
    /* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
    
    .container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
    /* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
    
    .container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
        background-color: #2196F3;
    }
    /* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
    
    .checkmark:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
    }
    /* Show the checkmark when checked */
    
    .container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
        display: block;
    }
    /* Style the checkmark/indicator */
    
    .container .checkmark:after {
        left: 9px;
        top: 5px;
        width: 5px;
        height: 10px;
        border: solid white;
        border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    
    #Pref {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pref-value1" class="form-group Pref">
    <label class="container">
        <input id="checkbox1" name="preferred1" type="checkbox" value="false">
        <span id="pref-a" class="checkmark" style="margin: -2px 1px;" />
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Like you suggested, I grabbed the wrong target tag. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You check the wrong element.

Try with the correct selector instead `this`. In your case this is a reference to the span element and not the checkbox element

e.g.

```
 $("#checkbox1").is(':checked')
```